# CSS issues with dynamic php page

Tags: php, css, dynamic, xhtml, css-tables

I am no beginner with HTML and CSS... but I am with PHP. I have a very tiny dynamically generated PHP page that creates a table and fills it with numbers. The CSS is working on random items, very weirdly and I'm not sure what is going on. The `<body>` tag CSS is not working at all. Not one property is being affected by it. The `table.temps` css is not working either, but if I remove it, then the `<th>` tag looses its styling. This is for a homework assignment and I know it's an easy fix, I've just been having the worst time with CSS and PHP lately.

It's all one page, and its relatively small, so here is the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<title>Lab 1</title> 

<style type="text/css">
<!-- Declare document <body> styles -->
body{
    background-color: #9FDBFF;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

<!-- Declare document table styles -->
table.temps {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: #333;
}

th {
    background: blue;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}

.colorIt {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<?php

$intTableTotalWidth = 8;
$intTableTotalHeight = 8;
$intCount = 1;

print("<table class='temps'>");
print("<th>Farenheight</th>");
print("<th>Celcius</th>");

for ($intHeight = 0; $intHeight < $intTableTotalHeight; $intHeight++) {
print("<tr>");

for ($intWidth = 0; $intWidth < $intTableTotalWidth; $intWidth++) {

    if ($intCount % 2 == 0){
        print("<td class='colorIt'>" . $intCount ."</td>");
    }
    else {
        print ("<td>" . $intCount . "</td>");
    }

    $intCount++;
}

print("</tr>");
}

print("</table>");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT: My fault people, I didn't even realize I was using HTML comments in the CSS. It's internal CSS so the CSS comments don't change color in the HTML document which was throwing me off. I fixed the issue. I appreciate your input!**

Comment: Use CSS comments in the style block, don't use html comments.  /* */ vs <!-- -->

Comment: Also, your `<th>` elements should be wrapped in a `<tr>`

Answer (score 3):

You are using html comments in the style tag. This is not allowed. You should **never** use html comments  in style and script tags.It's not allowed. Remove them and it will all work.

Answer (score 2):

remove these lines

```
<!-- Declare document <body> styles -->
<!-- Declare document table styles -->
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `<th>` tags should be embeded in `<tr>` tags: `<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>`.
2. You are outputing more cells / row than columns defined with `<th>`. If you want a `<th>` to contain two columns, you should use `<th colspan="2">col1</th>`.

Answer (score 0):

much easier sollution: have `session_start()` at begining of .php file, put all your theme in a array and later, include stylesheet

```
session_start()
$theme=array("links"=>"#ff0000", "bkg"=>"#00ff00");
$_SESSION["Theme"]=$theme;
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.php">
```

and your stylesheet look like this: 
default.php

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["Theme"])) {
    extract($_SESSION["Theme"]);
    header("Content-type: text/css");
} else {
// this part is for proper coloring the file, editor will see <style> 
// but when loaded from main file <style> will be discarded     
?>
<style>
<?php } ?>
a {
   color:<?=$links?>;      
}

body {
    background-color: <?=$bkg?>;
}
```